# Filtering a complex SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Unit - hmy, scode, hProperty

InsurancePolicy - hmy, hUnit, dtEffective, sStatus

```
Select MAX(i2.dtEffective) as maxdate, u.hMy, MAX(i2.hmy) as InsuranceId, 
    i2.sStatus 
from unit u 
    left join InsurancePolicy i2 on i2.hUnit = u.hMy 
        and i2.sStatus in ('Active', 'Cancelled', 'Expired')  
where u.hProperty = 2
Group By u.hmy, i2.sStatus
order by u.hmy
```

This query will return values for the Insurance Policy with the latest Effective Date (`Max(dtEffective)`).  I added `Max(i2.hmy)` so if there was more than one Insurance Policy for the latest Effective Date, it will return the one with the highest ID (`i2.hmy`) in the database.

Suppose there was a Unit that had 3 Insurance Policies attached with the same latest effective date and all have different sStatus'.
The result would look like this:

```
maxdate    UnitID    InsuranceID    sStatus
1/23/12    2949      1938           'Active'
1/23/12    2949      2343           'Cancelled'
1/23/12    2949      4323           'Expired'
```

How do I filter the results so that if there are multiple Insurance Policies with different Status' for the same unit and same date, then we choose the Insurance Policy with the `'Active'` Status first, if one doesn't exist, choose `'Cancelled'`, and if that doesn't exist, choose `'Expired'`.

Comment: I would be concerned if this thing is happening. You should be storing datetime ifnormation so you can get teh latest one if they are on the same date. Other wise how to dyou the sctive was last , maybe the last action was cancelled

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a matter of proper [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) of `InsurancePolicy`'s rows and then joining `Unit` to the set of the former's top-ranked rows:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY hUnit
      ORDER BY dtEffective DESC, sStatus, hmy DESC
    )
  FROM InsurancePolicy
)
SELECT
  i2.dtEffective AS maxdate,
  u.hMy,
  i2.hmy AS InsuranceId,
  i2.sStatus
FROM Unit u
  LEFT JOIN ranked i2 ON i2.hUnit = u.hMy AND i2.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this work with one SQL statement but it will be nearly unreadable to your everyday t-sql developer.  I would suggest breaking this query up into a few steps.

First, I would declare a table variable and place all the records that require no manipulation into this table (ie - Units that do not have multiple statuses for the same date = good records).

Then, get a list of your records that need work done on them (multiple statuses on the same date for the same UnitID) and place them in a table variable.  I would create a "rank" column within this table variable using a case statement as illustrated here:

> Pseudocode: WHEN Active THEN 1 ELSE WHEN Cancelled THEN 2 ELSE WHEN Expired THEN 3 END

Then delete records where 2 and 3 exist with a 1
Then delete records where 2 exists and 3

Finally, merge this updated table variable with your table variable containing your "good" records.

It is easy to get sucked into trying to do too much within one SQL statement.  Break up the tasks to make it easier for you to develop and more manageable in the future.  If you have to edit this SQL in a few years time you will be thanking yourself, not to mention any other developers that may have to take over your code.